# How to fit a Prony series to data in PGFPlot?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit Prony series to my viscoelasticity data in PGFPlots. The problem I am running with is how to mathematically define the Prony series that `gnuplot` can recognise the function and do the fitting. The Prony series is `\sum_{i=0}^{k} G_k * \frac{x*a_k}{1+(x*a_k)^2}`. Anyone know how to do this?
Here is the complete code I am using:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}




\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\write18{}

\begin{filecontents}{double.dat}
100     96413.1
68.1292 81638.4
46.4159 68107.2
31.6228 56025.6
21.5443 45408.8
14.678  36326.7
10      28716.9
6.81292 22417.4
4.64159 17326.6
3.16228 13270.2
2.15443 10111.3
1.4678  7655.31
1       5775.24
0.68129 4316.84
0.46416 3230.06
0.31623 2394.33
0.21544 1769.85
0.14678 1301.58
0.1     950.86
0.06813 688.064
0.04642 494.033
0.03162 352.155
0.02154 249.154
0.01468 176.579
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false,
    axis line style=thick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    separate axis lines,
    x tick style={black,thick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={$\omega$ [rad/s]},
    xmin=0.01,xmax=100,
    xtick={0.01,0.1,1,10,100},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,thick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={$G'$ [Pa]},
    ymin=1,ymax=1000000,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]   

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.3,thick,fill=blue!50}] file {double.dat};

\addplot+[raw gnuplot,red,thick,no marks,smooth] gnuplot {
set log x;
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k} G_k * \frac{x*a_k}{1+(x*a_k)^2};
G=1000;
k=10;
a=1;
fit f(x) 'double.dat' using 1:2 via G_k,a_k,k;
plot [x=0.01:100] f(x);
};


\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can manually write the Prony series for `k=4` but I need to use more elements, say `k=100`.

Comment: Please make the question a bit clearer. What are the G_k and a_k? The k-th entries in your table? And `i` seems to be your summation index. However, the argument of the sum does not depend on `i`.

Comment: The function definition in the gnuplot program is no valid gnuplot code, i expect `sum [<var> = <start> : <end>] <expression>`! Do you want to use latex to generate the Prony series for use in the gnuplot program? Please minimize your example to the core problem as far as possible.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Terribly sorry for the mistake. It must be `G_i` and `a_i`, these are the parameters for generalised Maxwell model. Also, `i=0` cannot be, must start from 1. The correct function to be fitted is `\sum_{i=1}^{k}  \frac{G_i*x*a_i}{1+(x*a_i)^2}`.

Comment: Well, the answer below was assuming this. (Note that pgfplots starts numbering its rows at 0.)

Comment: @hefe I used the following expression `f(x)=sum[i=1:100] G_i*x*a_i/(1+(x*a_i)^2)` you suggested. Texpad compiles it without errors. The only trouble is that the gnuplot doesn't take the summation over `x=1:100` range. It only calculates for one element `x=1`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Gagik I am not fluent in gnuplot. Maybe you split the gnuplot problem and the pgfplots problem and solve them separately? Maybe a dedicated gnuplot question at stackexchange?

Comment: It is a bit frustrating that you seem not even to look at the answer.

Comment: @hefe I'm gonna try to explain it more clearly. I would like to fit a function to my data on a log-log plot in pgfplots. The function I wanna fit is a series, called Prony series. Since it is a non-linear fitting, I am using gnuplot. I can get a good fit if I manually define the series as followwing `f(x)=G_1*x*a_1/(1+(x*a_1)^2) + G_2*x*a_2/(1+(x*a_2)^2) + G_3*x*a_3/(1+(x*a_3)^2) + G_4*x*a_4/(1+(x*a_4)^2) + G_5*x*a_5/(1+(x*a_5)^2) + G_6*x*a_6/(1+(x*a_6)^2)`. My question is: how can I write this in series form? I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

To me the definition of the sum is not very clear, this is a possible interpretation. If the interpretation is wrong, it is easy to change this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}




\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\begin{filecontents*}{double.dat}
100     96413.1
68.1292 81638.4
46.4159 68107.2
31.6228 56025.6
21.5443 45408.8
14.678  36326.7
10      28716.9
6.81292 22417.4
4.64159 17326.6
3.16228 13270.2
2.15443 10111.3
1.4678  7655.31
1       5775.24
0.68129 4316.84
0.46416 3230.06
0.31623 2394.33
0.21544 1769.85
0.14678 1301.58
0.1     950.86
0.06813 688.064
0.04642 494.033
0.03162 352.155
0.02154 249.154
0.01468 176.579
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{double.dat}\mydata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\mydata}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\edef\irun{0}%
\loop
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\irun}{[index]0}\of\mydata%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\currai{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\irun}{[index]1}\of\mydata%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\currGi{\pgfplotsretval}%
\ifnum\irun=0\relax
\edef\PronySum{\currGi*(\currai*x)/(1+\currai*\currai)}%
\else
\edef\PronySum{\PronySum+\currGi*(\currai*x)/(1+pow(\currai*x,2))}%
\fi
\edef\irun{\the\numexpr\irun+1}%
\expandafter\edef\csname PronySum\irun\endcsname{\PronySum}%
\ifnum\irun<\numrows\relax
\repeat
\def\PartialPronySum#1{\csname PronySum#1\endcsname}
\begin{loglogaxis}[%declare function={PronySum(\k)=\PartialPronySum\k;};
    enable tick line clipping=false,
    axis line style=thick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    separate axis lines,
    x tick style={black,thick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={$\omega$ [rad/s]},
    xmin=0.01,xmax=100,
    xtick={0.01,0.1,1,10,100},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,thick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={$G'$ [Pa]},
    ymin=1,ymax=1000000,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]   

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.3,thick,fill=blue!50}] file {double.dat};
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[domain=0.01:100,red,thick] {\PartialPronySum{10}};}
\temp
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the fitting part in this answer. However, no meaningful response is possible until the ambiguities in the question is resolved.

Comment: @hefe This answer enables the OP to compute sums over expressions which draw the coefficients from a table. No more, no less. If they come up with a formula that provides one with a proper fit, then this answer can be used to visualize the result. To me it is not even clear if this it supposed to be a fitting function.